# Running MapReduce code that uses zooKeeper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-zookeeper

I want to ask about how to execute a MapReduce java code that uses zooKeeper.

My first code is just to create a variable (znode) and to modify it by each mapper.
So I modified the wordCount code just to test zookeeper for the first time.
When I run it using the eclipse console, everything goes well, so I can see the changes on the value of the znode, etc.

However, I was trying to execute it using linux command line:

```
**bin/hadoop jar ./myjar.jar algo.WordCount /input.txt /out
```

I got the following error

```
**Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.Watcher
```

Although that I added the path of the jar file using conf.set("mapred.jar","...."); in the mapreduce code but I don't know why it did not recognize the classes of zookeeper.

Any idea?

Comment: Check [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) blog from Cloudera on how to include 3rd party libraries in MR jobs.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) , I am reading the blog to see if there solutions are feasible.

Comment: I solved the problem .. In fact my problem was not related to Hadoop, It was a problem with the generated jar file ..